# Problems restoring partition with "fsarchiver restfs": it gets stuck!

Tags: backup, restore

I am having problems restoring my partition on a new SSD with `fsarchiver`.

The creation of the archive of my partition went pretty smooth, but I can not restore it. I do not get any error, but it basically gets stuck.

After one day and one night of extracting the archive, I killed it and I ran it again, this time in verbose mode, and still.. no error appears: it starts mke2fs and gets stuck.

Any idea on how to solve it? Do I have to do anything on the new SSD before starting the `fsarchiver restfs ...`? Might this be the problem?

Comment: Is it using much memory, much CPU or much I/O the whole time?

Comment: That's the thing: it is not using much of anything. It looks like it is doing nothing.

Comment: Could you start it again, with `strace`? You could connect `strace` to a running process, but if it just hangs, there will be nothing to see I think.

Comment: You can at least see in which function it hangs - which may not be useful - like this: `strace -p2326`

Comment: Sorry for the late and thanks for your reply. I fixed it. It was actually a silly mistake, because I had not made my partitions before calling `restfs`. Now I am trying to regenerate the grub since I can not boot. Let's see..

Comment: That's great! Would you like to write a short answer to this question yourself, and then accept it as correct? Otherwise this question will stay here for along time...

Comment: sure, thanks. I am still having problems trying to boot. :(

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! I just needed to partition the drive before starting the restore procedure with fsarchiver.